# Change macOS Mojave system icons

Tags: macos, finder, mojave, icon

In the past, I changed my folder icons for Applications, Downloads, Documents and for applications like Mail Safari.  Now many have reverted or gone to a white page picture.

How can I replace them with my own icons again?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). All the best!

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/100332/how-can-i-change-a-smart-folders-icon-without-changing-the-default-icon

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change Finder Icon in macOS Catalina without rebooting?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/376279/change-finder-icon-in-macos-catalina-without-rebooting)

Answer (score 1):

The manual way is to go to the system folder using finder go to folder command 
shortcut Shift Command G ⇧⌘G

`/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources/`

Rename the original icon and then name the new icon file with the original name. 
Will need to be an admin user and enter your password when doing this

Using a dedicated program may be easier see [Liteicon](https://freemacsoft.net/liteicon/) for a free download.

The file will need to be a Mac icon file .icns

I create my icons with [Affinity Designer](https://affinity.serif.com/en-gb/designer/) export to a 1024 X 1024 PNG then use [iConvert Icons](https://iconverticons.com) to make the icon files.
Any photo or vector graphics tool will work and there are other converters.