# Change Finder Icon in macOS Catalina without rebooting?

Tags: macos, finder, dock, catalina

On previous versions of macOS, it was possible to change the Finder icon in /System/Library/CoreServices/Dock.app/Contents/Resources/. However, this doesn't seem possible in Catalina anymore, even if I try disabling SIP.

I’d love a process that works immediately, but any solution will be considered.

Are there step by step instructions how to place the new image for Catalina systems?

Comment: In Catalina you can't change items in the system partition, even as root - it is read-only.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With all default security measures of Catalina enabled you can't change neither Finder's icon nor Dock's Finder icon without rebooting.

To overcome the involved hurdles (and re-enable them later), you have to reboot at least twice.

These are:

1. disable SIP
2. mount your system volume read/write (usually it's read-only)

Step-by-step How-To:

1. Boot to macOS Recovery (AKA Recovery Mode) by booting|rebooting and pressing <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> right after the startup chime
2. After booting is completed you'll see a window titled *macOS Utilites*. In the menubar open Utilities > Terminal
3. In the Terminal type `csrutil disable` and hit <kbd>⏎ Return/Enter</kbd> to execute the command
4. In the Terminal type `reboot` and hit <kbd>⏎ Return/Enter</kbd>
5. After rebooting to the standard macOS and logging on to a user with admin privileges, open Terminal in the folder /Applications/Utilities/
6. In the Terminal type `sudo mount -rw /` and hit <kbd>⏎ Return/Enter</kbd> to execute the command
7. Now modify Dock's Finder icons: (*/System/Library/CoreServices/Dock.app/Contents/Resources/finder.png* and */System/Library/CoreServices/Dock.app/Contents/Resources/finder@2x.png*) or Finder's Finder icons: */System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app/Contents/Resources/Finder.icns*
8. To remove the original icon type:

   ```
    sudo rm /System/Library/CoreServices/Dock.app/Contents/Resources/finder.png
   ```

   and hit <kbd>⏎ Return/Enter</kbd>
9. Copy the new icons with the Terminal to the Resources folder(s). Example (assuming the new Finder icon *finder.png* is on your desktop):

   ```
    sudo cp /Users/your_username/Desktop/finder.png /System/Library/CoreServices/Dock.app/Contents/Resources/
   ```

   and hit <kbd>⏎ Return/Enter</kbd>
10. Remove Dock's icon cache:

    ```
    sudo find /private/var/folders/ -name com.apple.dock.iconcache -exec rm {} \;
    ```

and hit <kbd>⏎ Return/Enter</kbd>
11. Kill the Dock.app: `killall Dock` and hit <kbd>⏎ Return/Enter</kbd>
12. Reboot to Boot to macOS Recovery and re-enable SIP by typing in the Terminal `csrutil enable` and <kbd>⏎ Return/Enter</kbd> to execute the command.
13. In the Terminal type `reboot` and hit <kbd>⏎ Return/Enter</kbd>
14. Proof for the modified Finder icon in the Dock:

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

After point updates (e.g. 10.15.2) the icons will be replaced probably and you have to re-do the whole icon customization.

---

Alternative way (kudos to [user3439894](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/115523/user3439894)) without disabling SIP and only one reboot:

1. Download/prepare your pics (i.e. finder.png and finder@2x.png) e.g on your Desktop
2. Boot to macOS Recovery (AKA Recovery Mode) by booting|rebooting and pressing <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> right after the startup chime
3. After booting is completed you'll see a window titled *macOS Utilites*. In the menubar open Utilities > Terminal
4. Here I assume *Macintosh HD* is the name of your main volume and *user_name* is your user name. Replace them accordingly with the names in your setup in the commands below . In the Terminal enter (hit <kbd>⏎ Return/Enter</kbd> after each line):

   ```
    cp /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/Users/user_name/Desktop/finder.png /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/System/Library/CoreServices/Dock.app/Contents/Resources/
    cp /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/Users/user_name/Desktop/finder@2x.png /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/System/Library/CoreServices/Dock.app/Contents/Resources/
    find /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/private/var/folders/ -name com.apple.dock.iconcache -exec rm {} \;
    reboot
   ```

If you are unable to navigate to the path `/Volumes/Macintosh\ HD`, make sure your disk is mounted. Follow the steps below to mount your disk.

1. Quit the terminal
2. Select the Disk Utility option
3. On the left side of the window, you will see the list of Disks where Macintosh HD might be greyed out. Click that and select **mount** from the central top panel.
4. Quit the Disk Utility and open terminal again. You will be able to navigate to the paths mentioned above

---

A quick & dirty bash script `iconreplacement.sh` (which can be refined) based on user3439894's alternative approach automates some tasks:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Variables

DOCKRES="/Volumes/$SYSVOLNAME/System/Library/CoreServices/Dock.app/Contents/Resources/"

#Change Finder icons in Dock.app, clean Dock's icon cache and reboot to normal system

if [ ! -d "/Users/$USER" ]; then
    cp "/Volumes/$SYSVOLNAME/Users/$USR/Desktop/finder.png" "$DOCKRES"
    cp "/Volumes/$SYSVOLNAME/Users/$USR/Desktop/finder@2x.png" "$DOCKRES"
    find "/Volumes/$SYSVOLNAME/private/var/folders/" -name com.apple.dock.iconcache -exec rm {} \;
    reboot
fi

#Reboot to Recovery Mode
    
sudo nvram "recovery-boot-mode=unused" > /dev/null 2>&1
sudo reboot > /dev/null 2>&1
```

The variable `DOCKRES` defines the path to the Resource folder of Dock.app in Recovery Mode.

The `if` statement detects whether the Mac is booted to Recovery Mode. Only then the resource files will be copied to Dock.app's Resource folder, the iconcache will be deleted and the Mac reboots.

The `sudo` commands reboot your Mac to Recovery Mode. `sudo` doesn't exist in the Recovery Mode base system and executing it throws an error. In my environment this happened sometimes because reboot was too slow to kill everything (or `sudo ...` too fast). The error message is suppressed with `... > /dev/null 2>&1`.

Move the bash script to your admin user's Desktop. The two Dock resource files (finder.png and finder@2x.png) have to reside on the same user's desktop.

To execute the bash script (save any open files and quit all apps first) and reboot to Recovery Mode enter in Terminal:

```
cd Desktop
./iconreplacement.sh
```

In Recovery Mode open the Terminal. The shell command and the script require to set the name of your main volume and the admin user. Example:

```
SYSVOLNAME="Macintosh HD"
USR=capatane
```

So enter and replace *Main_Volume_Name* and *user_name* accordingly:

```
SYSVOLNAME="Main_Volume_Name"
USR=user_name
cd "/Volumes/$SYSVOLNAME/Users/$USR/Desktop/"
. ./iconreplacement.sh
```

The first `.`  (dot and space) is intentional and is required to export the user definded variables (`SYSVOLNAME` & `USR`) to the shell script!

**Use this script at your own risk. No responsibility is taken over for errors, omissions, interruptions, defects, delays during operation etc.**

Comment: You do not need to disable **System Integrity Protection** nor make `/` writable and you only have to reboot once. 1. Prep your images while booted normally. 2. Reboot to **macOS Recovery** and using **Terminal** from the **Utilities** menu, make the necessary modifications to the _file system_ without using the `sudo` _command_, but prefacing the normal _pathnames_ with e.g. `/Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/...` where `...` is the rest of the normal _pathname_. When done, reboot, that's it!

Comment: Actually, I'd `bash` _script_ the entire process from a normal boot and then run the `bash` _script_ when booted from **macOS Recovery**.

Comment: @user3439894 We were thinking about scripting this at work just last week. Do you have a github where we can knock out a framework for this?

Comment: klanomath, to answer your now deleted comment... When booted from **macOS Recovery** and using **Terminal**, it is already a _root_ **Terminal**, hence no need to use `sudo` and **System Integrity Protection** is not actually active on the e.g. **Macintosh HD** and changes can be made at will. From **macOS Recovery**, `csrutil disable` is applicable when next booted to _normal mode_.

Comment: @bmike, No I do not have a **GitHub** page, however klanomath's answer already has the _framework_.

Comment: @user3439894 You are right! I always thought /System/Library and other files and folders are **always** protected by SIP.

Comment: I’ll post here if I make a tool to automate this...

Comment: BTW When I want to _reboot_ to **macOS Recovery** from a _normal boot_, the easiest way for me is to use **Terminal** with the following _compound command, `sudo nvram "recovery-boot-mode=unused"; sudo reboot`. This will boot one directly to **macOS Recovery** and the `nvram` _setting_ doesn't survive the _reboot_ from **macOS Recovery**, so no need to make any additional changes to `nvram` afterwards.  (Note: IIRC This is only useful with **macOS Sierra** and later. )

Comment: @user3439894, that’s two reboots

Comment: @WGroleau, The reference to rebooting once is rebooting once to macOS Recovery, **not** the total number of reboots!