# Enable SIP without reboot?

Tags: macos, sip

Some time ago, I read somewhere that Apple had decided to provide a way to *enable* SIP without a recovery reboot.  If that’s true, how?  It isn’t `csrutil enable` (at least not on my system).

It would be an obvious security risk to allow disable in normal use.  But when I need to edit something “special,” it would be nice to do it with two reboots instead of four.

Of course, it may be that what I read was neither from Apple nor accurate.  But I definitely read it, and my possibly faulty memory says it was in release notes for one of the updates.

No matter how much I try to make "enable" mandatory, web search gives me tons of hits on "disable."

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/261684/disable-sip-without-recovery-mode

Comment: A "not possible" that's three or more years old doesn't answer the question on whether Apple had since provided a way to make it possible.  Nor on what that method is.  Also note that I said "enable," not "disable" and "reboot," not "recovery mode."

Comment: The other Q asks for disabling so at least in theory there could be a way to enable it anyway. Nevertheless can you please edit your question to focus on the actual issue? Right now there is a lot of unrelated stuff in it and the question primarily is in the title itself.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/376279/change-finder-icon-in-macos-catalina-without-rebooting

Comment: The manual page for `csrutil`, in **macOS Catalina**, for the _verb_ `enable` does say, "Only available in Recovery OS."

Comment: *"it would be nice to do it with two reboots instead of four"* Not an answer but resetting PRAM (with alt+cmd+p+r) turns on SIP again so that saves booting into recovery to turn it on again and you only need **3** reboots rather than **4**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, you can use `sudo csrutil clear`, follow by a reboot, to enable SIP. So the command enables SIP without a reboot, however this does not go into effect until the next reboot. This get it down to 3 reboots to enable/disable SIP.

You can get it down to two reboot by using [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/).

If you want to disable SIP with a single reboot, then install rEFInd. If you specify the `--usedefault` option when [installing rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/refind-install.html), then rEFInd will be installed to the `/EFI/BOOT` folder in the EFI volume. This will allow rEFInd to appear in the Startup Manager. A boot to rEFInd is almost instantaneous, as opposed to macOS Recovery which is not. Once rEFInd is properly installed, changing the status of SIP can be done by the following steps.

1. Reboot and hold down the option key to boot to the Startup Manager.
2. Select to boot to rEFInd.
3. From the rEFInd menu, select to enable or disable SIP.
4. From the rEFInd menu, select to boot to macOS.

If you have Windows or another Linux installed which uses the `/EFI/BOOT` folder in the EFI partition, then you will need to create another small partition for rEFInd to boot from. This can be another EFI partition, a FAT32 formatted or ExFAT formatted partition. You can even put rEFInd on a flash drive, if you do not rEFInd installed on your internal drive.

I also should note that rEFInd now includes [gdisk](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/), which is a command that is easier to use than the `gpt` command included with macOS. So, if you need SIP temporarily disabled to edit the partitioning on `disk0`, you can do this in only 1 boot.

Comment: In http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/features.html is states "Beginning with version 0.10.0, the ability to adjust Apple System Integrity Protection (SIP; aka "rootless" or "CSR") settings. These settings control what features are off-limits even to root in macOS 10.11 (El Capitan) and later. To use this feature, you must set specific CSR values on refind.conf's csr_values line and add csr_rotate to the showtools line." ... Is the still necessary to do?

Comment: @user3439894: You probably have to edit the `refind.conf` file and specify  `csr_rotate` in `showtools` and enable `csr_values`. To use `gdisk` you may have to specify `gdisk` in `showtools`

Comment: So then, it's not as straight forward as your answer leads one to believe. You have to install it, then specially configure it for it to work as you've described.

Comment: @user3439894: I was not trying to explain how to configure rEFInd. I was trying to indicate that rEFInd's functionality has been expanded beyond that of just being a boot manager. In this case, you would not need any of rEFInd's original boot manager functionality. Instead you would be using the added ability to enable/disable SIP by installing rEFInd so it would appear in the Startup Manager.

Comment: At first glance, this sounds like it might be worth doing.  I’ll have to think about it.

Comment: +1 - this is the quickest way.  Note if you run `refind-install` without the `--usedefault` option it will install to `EFI/refind` rather than `EFI/BOOT`.  This means you don't *need* to create another partition if you are using `EFI/BOOT` for something else.

Comment: @Ix07: If rEFInd is installed to `EFI/refind`, then rEFInd will not appear in the Startup Manager. So, if you go this route, then you will have to **also** use rEFInd as the startup manager in place of the default Startup Manager provided by the firmware.

Comment: Since I reboot once in a while anyway, the first paragraph answers the question as asked, but the rEFInd sounds like a good idea for anyone who needs to bypass SIP often.