# How to disable preview for some types (EPS) of files thumbnails in Mac finder?

Tags: macos, finder, catalina, quicklook, quicklook-plugin

I am stocker and draw tons of images in Adobe Illustrator. All images are being saved in pair of EPS and JPG format. I updated to Catalina on my Mac and the Finder now shows preview for both EPS and JPG Thumbnail and it is impossible now to work for me with tons of duplicated files visually.  Before my Finder is shown only preview for JPG and all was polite and good.

I attached how I what to see all in finder. Buy the way, all old folders still as I want, but all new files created - there is .eps file preview

[image: EPS & JPEG File List]

Answer (score 2):

You need to disable `/System/Library/QuickLook/EPS.qlgenerator`.  You can rename it to append `.backup` to that & then rename it back to original to restore it.

OR you can simply make a copy somewhere else and delete this quicklook generator.

You may need to run

```
qlmanage -r
```

after that.

The way I reached there is:

```
mdls /path/to/some/epsFile/pwrdLogo.eps   -name kMDItemContentTypeTree
```

& then searching the output of

```
qlmanage -m
```

for  one of these

```
kMDItemContentTypeTree = (
    "com.adobe.encapsulated-postscript",
    "public.item",
    "public.data",
    "com.adobe.postscript",
    "com.adobe.encapsulated-postscript",
    "public.composite-content",
    "public.content"
)
```

Comment: Surely you can't modify qlgenerators in `/System` in Catalina?

Comment: @benwiggy it was suggested in a linked question. I didn’t try that. I’m on Mojave.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply. Wanted to try it yesterday evening, but could not remove or rename file in system folder $(( Did not know that it is so hard in mac.. wasted about 2 hours to do it, read tons of manuals and still with no luck. I am the only administrator of my mac, but it says I have no permission to remove or rename any file there. Will try something today, and let you know. If you know how, please tell me! %)

Comment: @benwiggy  do you think I should suggest disabling SIP, using the four step method provided in https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/376279/change-finder-icon-in-macos-catalina-without-rebooting ? ВладЛукьянов do it on your own risk. Only proceed IF the issue is really so big that you absolutely need to do so.

Comment: @ankii thank you. I am really frustrated and afraid already, thought it should be an easy way and step for my task. But it looks really dangerous :) And yes, it looks like you need to operate in Recovery mode to manage any system files %) Do not sure already, if this costs or not.. but will think.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of modifying your system, use a [Smart Folder](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/create-or-change-a-smart-folder-on-mac-mchlp2804/mac) to filter out what you're working on.

I'm no artist by any means, but there are times I need to utilize Photoshop or Illustrator to modify some images.  Since I need to work with PSDs which also get thumbnail previews, I create a Smart Folder that searches that folder with limited scope in criteria.

For example, in the image below, I created one (for this answer) that searches my Desktop for all images.  You're not limited to what you can search for - filenames, extensions, types and even meta data!

[image: Smart Folder Results]

I keep these smart folders on my desktop or in a place with convenient access.  Like in your scenario, I'll put the smart folder at the "head" of the images folder with all of its sub folders.  I can then open it and just get all of my PSDs without the clutter of everything else.

**How to create a Smart Folder**

Simply click on *File* in the Finder menu bar, and select *New Smart Folder.*  Just set your search criteria and away you go!

[image]

Comment: I do not need to change search at all. I need to change PREVIEW of thumbnails in finder for any folders of my mac.

Comment: You’re missing the point of my answer.  The idea is to filter out what you want to see rather than modify your system to *force* it from its default behavior - to show previews for one file and not another