# Quick look - Way to turn off sound by default?

Tags: catalina, sound-volume, quicklook

I like using quick look to see what a file is so i sort it, but its annoying when theres movie and audio files that play sound when i open them. I just want to see what the video is i dont need to hear the sound, is there a way i can mute it by default? Thanks.

Comment: Turning off audio on when “quick looking” an audio file would defeat the purpose.  I don’t believe there is a way to disable this other than muting your sound output.

Comment: I meant for video files. also i like to scroll down my folders and i dont want sound playing. thanks for the response

Comment: Just scrolling won't play a file.  You have to hit space to quick look.  But if this is a problem, [create a smart folder](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/388838/119271) and filter *out* audio/video files.

Comment: Well it does. Just using arrow keys to scroll through the folder makes the sound play.

Comment: worse, if you mute it, it unmutes back to the default volume on the next media file.